# Preloading pages with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, document-ready, preloader

I would like to know if the function `$(window).on('load', function() { ... }` in `preload-min.js` takes in consideration all the code in the `index.html` and `main-min.js` before triggering.

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>

    ... html code ...

    <script src="dist/main-min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/preloader-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main-min.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 ... js code ...

})
```

preload-min.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function() {

    ... js code ...

  });
})
```

Comment: Cannot answer this questions with the limited information and script provided. Please include as much of your script and markup that is necessary to recreate your issue.

Comment: @ Korgrue I only focusing on the main query now. Thank you for the patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, `preloader-min.js` will wait until all of the content in `index.html` is loaded.  The two scripts will behave the same as if they were placed in one `<script>` tag in `index.html`.